# How to change DBeaver autocompletion key?

Tags: dbeaver

Is there a way to change the auto-complete key from <kbd>return</kbd> to <kbd>tab</kbd>?

I don't see it under the "auto-complete" settings, and I'm not finding anything promising under the "keys" setting either.

Comment: I found a related feature request. Looks like you're out of luck :-/ https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2316